# A word to describe someone who inherited something

Tags: word-choice

There are three actors in a basic inheritance process: the current possessor of the asset, e.g. Alice; the future possessor, e.g. Bob; and the asset itself, e.g. a house.

We can say the Bob a heir of Alice (or inheritor). We can say that Bob inherited a house from Alice.

What is the correct way to describe Bob as the one who inherits a house? The sentence "Bob is a heir of the house", in my opinion, implies that Bob will inherit something from the house, and not the house itself, isn't it?

---

Originally I wanted to address my future colleague who would maintain the project after me, like "The heir of this project should ..." (kinda vulgarly poetic tone is intentional).

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/someone-who-receives-or-collects-something According to the definition on this site, it is the correct choice to use **heir**. However I must point out, it should be _an heir_, not _a heir_.

Comment: By the way, do you want to know a word for the Bob and Alice story-line or do you want for that of the addressal of your colleague?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out __an__; turns out that I pronounced the silent H.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Perfectly both. I thought that the same word can be used in both cases (considering the tone of the second usage) but I admit that there might be better alternatives.

Comment: A person who benefits from a deceased person's will is sometimes called a [legatee](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/legatee). However I would call Bob the **inheritor** of the house. To call him the 'heir' of the house would be wrong. He is an  heir of the dead person.

Comment: Your future colleague is the inheritor of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use *heir* here. What needs to change is the preposition after it. See these examples from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/heir):

> - When her father died, she became the sole **heir *to*** his £40,000 estate.
> - The **heirs *of*** the company's founder control about 39% of the business.

In other words, *of* indicates the person being inherited from while *to* indicates the thing being inherited.

(Using *heir* to refer to the future maintainer of your project would give it a playful tone, as you’re not planning for someone dying.)